# Nested loop, how to parallel do on outside loop while sequently do on inside loop

Tags: fortran, openmp

A simple example:

```
module parameters
  implicit none
  integer :: i,step
  integer :: nt=5
  integer :: nelectron=5
  integer :: num_threads=2
  real(8) :: vt=855555.0
  real(8) :: dt=1.d-5
  real(8) :: vx1_old,vy1_old,vz1_old,t1,t2,x_old,y_old
  real(8) :: x_length=0.0
  real(8) :: y_length=0.0
  real(8) :: vx1_new,vy1_new,vz1_new,vzstore,x_new,y_new
end module parameters
program main
  use parameters
  use omp_lib
  implicit none
  integer :: thread_num

  !$ call omp_set_num_threads(num_threads)
  !$ call omp_set_nested(.false.)

  call cpu_time(t1)

  !$omp parallel
  !$omp& default(private) shared(x_length,y_length)
  !$omp& schedule(static,chunk)
  !$omp& reduction(+:x_length,y_length)
  !$omp do

  do i=1,nelectron

     do step=1,nt

        if(step==1)then           
           vx1_new=1.0
           vy1_new=1.0
           vz1_new=1.0
           x_new=1.0
           y_new=1.0 
        endif

        thread_num=omp_get_thread_num()
        write(*,*)"thread_num",thread_num
        write(*,*)"i",i
        write(*,*)"step",step
        write(*,*) 

        vx1_old=vx1_new
        vy1_old=vy1_new
        vz1_old=vz1_new
        x_old=x_new
        y_old=y_new

        x_length=x_length+x_old
        y_length=y_length+y_old
     enddo       
  enddo
  !$omp end do
  !$omp end parallel
  call cpu_time(t2)
  write(*,*)"x length=",x_length
  write(*,*)"y length=",y_length 
end program main
```

When I output the thread doing the actual work with `i` and `step`, I see somewhere weird:[image]

As you can see, thread 0 is doing the `i=6,step=1` while thread 1 is doing `i=6,step=2`.Why it changed thread when doing the same `i`? and How can I avoid this kind of situation. Meaning for each `i`, inner loop `step` is done on the same thread.

Comment: Never use `cpu_time()` in parallel programs and never trust the ordering of output from parallel programs. Two rules you must **always** follow.

Comment: Morever, I get this warning from gfortran, don't you get that? `Warning: !$OMP at (1) starts a commented line as it neither is followed by a space nor is a continuation line
nested_loop.f90:27.8:`

Comment: @VladimirF so the `step` loop for each `i` is done on the same thread or not, it is very important in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenMP only the outer most loop is parallelized, unless the `collapse` clause is used. That means that the whole iteration of the inner loop:

```
 do step=1,nt

    if(step==1)then           
       vx1_new=1.0
       vy1_new=1.0
       vz1_new=1.0
       x_new=1.0
       y_new=1.0 
    endif

    thread_num=omp_get_thread_num()
    write(*,*)"thread_num",thread_num
    write(*,*)"i",i
    write(*,*)"step",step
    write(*,*) 

    vx1_old=vx1_new
    vy1_old=vy1_new
    vz1_old=vz1_new
    x_old=x_new
    y_old=y_new

    x_length=x_length+x_old
    y_length=y_length+y_old
 enddo
```

is done by a single thread sequentially with a constant `i`. The thread gets a value of `i` and does the whole piece I quoted above for that value of `i` without any interaction with neighbouring threads.

However, as I pointed out in the comment, your syntax of the OpenMP directives is wrong. In this specific case it causes a race condition instead of the correct reduction for `x_length` and `y_length`. It AFAIK does not cause the problem you suspected to exist.

You should do

```
  !$omp parallel &
  !$omp& default(private)  &
  !$omp& shared(x_length,y_length)

  !$omp do schedule(static,5) reduction(+:x_length,y_length)
```

or just avoid the tricky line continuations

```
  !$omp parallel default(private) shared(x_length,y_length)

  !$omp do schedule(static,5) reduction(+:x_length,y_length)
```

As I commented above, do not trust output from parallel programs unless you take care of the ordering somehow and never use `cpu_time()` for parallel programs.